# macro activate workbook if name like

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that activates a workbook but i have to constantly change the name each month i need to run it. i cant figure out the syntax to activate the workbook with a name like xxx.

```
example Windows("CoventryPMPM102014.xlsx").Activate
```

next month the name will be "CoventryPMPM112014.xlsx" how do i get it to activate the workbook as long as its like "CoventryPMPM*"

I tried Windows("CoventryPMPM*").Activate but that doesnt work, how can i make this more dynamic

Comment: Probably easiest to loop the `workbooks` collection and compare Name to your pattern with the `Like` operator

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim st As String
    st = Format(Date, "mmyyyy")
    Windows("CoventryPMPM" & st & ".xlsx").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: there is no wildcard I can use for Windows("CoventryPMPM*.xlsx").Activate